# How to build an app for Cydia store?

Tags: iphone, cydia

I have built an app for Apple's App Store, now I want to submit the app to the Cydia store. How can I do this? Should I just post the app.zip file built for the App Store to the Cydia store?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a few differences compiling your app for Cydia vs the App Store. Big Boss does a good job explaining the difference in his post: 
[How to Compile for Cydia Submission](http://thebigboss.org/hosting-repository-cydia/submit-your-app/compile-for-cydia-submission)

Answer (score 7):

You should check out [**iOSOpenDev**](http://iosopendev.com/). It incorporates a lot of Cydia tweaks, Theos, Activator and all kinds of other things into Xcode. It allows you to create a new (Cydia) tweak of your choice and you can even launch that tweak on your device from Xcode.

To submit an "App Store" app, you would need to make sure you adjust the user directories. Since you will install the app into **/Applications**, there will be no sandbox; no Documents directory dedicated to just your application.

You will also need to sign your app with **ldid**. This "fake" code-signs your application so it can run in iOS. To submit the app to Cydia, you would need to find a repo you are comfortable with hosting the app, like [BigBoss](http://thebigboss.org/).

Be careful though, submitting an App Store app to Cydia could potentially get your app thrown out of the App Store and your developer account revoked.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of building an actual full application, I believe the development process is the same but the compiling and preperation of the binary is different.  The provided link is a good resource

If you intend to make a tweak which hooks into existing Apple classes and methods then you need something like theos by DHowett, a good basic [tutorial is here](http://filippobiga.tumblr.com/)

Comment: The author removed the tutorial due to taking alot of people clueless  as told on the site, I found the tutorial on waybackmachine http://web.archive.org/web/20110906012229/http://filippobiga.tumblr.com/ but we can't download the tutorial archive anymore :'(. Thanks to @WrightsCS, he gave an excellent solution with [iOSOpenDev](http://iosopendev.com/) :)

Answer (score 1):

u need to create a repo. or send them to MMi's collection

to make a repo read Saurik's Guide: [Here](http://www.saurik.com/id/7)

Or read the easier guide that MYI made for us at: [Here](http://modmyi.com/forums/cydia-support/402221-how-make-cydia-repository.html)

to submit a package to the MMI repo,
try the Developer Portal:
http://modmyi.com/mmi/

Some info regarding paid packages:
http://modmyi.com/cydia/cydiastorefaq/

Basically, all the content in your theme must be your own original work.
All the graphics / sounds must be created and owned by you.
If you have further questions, drop a note to the admins:
http://modmyi.com/sendmessage.php

Answer (score 0):

Well first of al if your app.zip is the .app file found in the payload folder of a .ipa file, then disregard this next step. Anyway, open up app.zip, go to payload, and then take out app.app. Make the app.app app.zip. Now go to http://www.myrepospace.com/iDeb and upload your app.zip. Then when it's done, download your new .deb file.

Answer (score 0):

Despite of the title you seem to ask about submission rather than (or in addition to) building. I'd consider this the one best reference:

http://cydia.saurik.com/faq/repositories.html

It is from Cydia itself and includes sschunara's links and other BigBoss references plus more.