# How can I upload an app to the jailbroken phone market

Tags: iphone, upload, jailbreak

I do not want to pay 99$ to upload an app so what is an alternative way I can upload my app for others to download, I am willing to put my app up for download for jailbroken phones.

Comment: jailbreak != off topic

Comment: @Jonathan, [app store questions are, though](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131388/would-questions-about-app-store-approval-be-appropriate-for-so).

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, that question you linked to does **not** say that app store questions are off-topic.  It specifically asks about *Apple approval*, which one *could* argue is subjective, and only answerable by Apple themselves.  *"What is an alternative to the App Store"* is not in any way subjective, and is answerable by loads of people who don't work for Apple.  Using an alternative to the official App Store requires **technical** steps that can only be performed by developers.  It's not merely a business question.  It's a programming question.

Comment: @user2230366, there's many choices for *repos*, if you do release an app through Cydia.  BigBoss is one of them.  [Here's a good reference on how to use the BigBoss repo](http://thebigboss.org/hosting-repository-cydia/submit-your-app/compile-for-cydia-submission).

Comment: I read this as a business question ("what alternatives to the Apple app store are available?"), and not a programming question, @Jonathan. Let's see how the answers play out, though.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, we won't see how the answers play out because people are trigger happy and love pressing close, especially when a question is about jailbreak.

Answer (score 2):

You can distribute your app via [Cydia](http://cydia.saurik.com/) - this question has some good answers on the topic: [How to build an app for Cydia store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756444/how-to-build-an-app-for-cydia-store)

Obviously this significantly reduces the number of people that can use the application - but as long as you don't have an issue with that, it should work.